# ¿Cómo verificar si una subcadena cumple con una expresión regular dentro de la cadena?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo varias parejas de entradas para buscar dentro de un texto usando JavaScript. Cada pareja consiste en una cadena corta (por ejemplo, `cc`) y el contexto en el que debe estar (digamos `[^\d]cc[a-z]`). Quiero localizar las coincidencias dentro del texto, pero no es tan fácil como usar una función del tipo `indexOf([^\d]cc[a-z])` porque no toma como referencia la subcadena que me importa (`cc`).

Por ejemplo, si el texto es `1cccd` debería obtener `2` como salida, pero `'1cccd'.indexOf([^\d]cc[a-z])` da `1` porque esa es la posición donde encuentra `[^\d]`.

Había intentado algo como `'1cccd'.replace([^\d]cc[a-z], '$&').slice(i).indexOf('cc') == 0` (donde i avanza a lo largo del texto), pero esto encuentra todas las coincidencias de `cc` sin importar el contexto.

También traté de usar los grupos de captura de `match` para medir la cantidad de caracteres a la izquierda de la subcadena: `var tmp = '1cccd'.match(([^\d])cc[a-z]); return tmp.index+tmp[1].length;`. Pero no puedo restringir esto a una zona del texto porque `match` no acepta la opción `lastIndex` de las expresiones regulares. Pensé usar `exec` que sí acepta `lastIndex`, pero no sabe de grupos de captura. (EDITO: `exec` **sí** usa grupos de captura, como se ve en las respuestas abajo)

Otra posible solución era usar un `lookbehind`, pero JavaScript no los acepta.

¿Hay alguna forma directa de verificar si una subcadena en una posición dada cumple con una expresión regular?

Comment: No acabo de entender que es exactamente lo que buscas obtener, cual es el indice que quieres obtener? el del numero? el de la primera 'c'? el de la segunda 'c'?. Por lo que dices parece que quieres el de la primera 'c', pero dices que deberia ser indice 2, la primera 'c' es indice 1, el numero 1 es indice 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo unos pocos navegadores son compatible con *"positives lookbehind"*. No obstante, puedes intentar una combinación de `exec` y `lastIndexOf`. Es decir (por ejemplo):

```js
var regex = /(?=[^\d])cc(?=[a-z])/g;
var str = '1cccdcca';

for (var array; (array = regex.exec(str)) !== null;) {
    console.log("Encontrado: " + array[0]);
    console.log("Posición: " + (str.substring(0, regex.lastIndex + 1).lastIndexOf(array[0])));
}
```

Comment: Tienes razón en que `exec` sí puede usar grupos de captura. Marco tu respuesta como aceptada y pongo ĺa versión final de mi código abajo.

Answer (score 0):

Este código encuentra todas las instancias de la cadena dentro del contexto de la expresión regular, pero esta debe ser ingresada con las diagonales invertidas codificadas (\\ en lugar de \).

```
var texto = '3cccdccccc';      // entrada
var cadena = 'cc';             // entrada
var regex = '[^\\d]cc[^\\d]';  // entrada (con \\ en lugar de \)
var regexsistema = new RegExp('('+regex.substring(0,regex.indexOf(cadena))+')'+regex.substring(regex.indexOf(cadena),regex.length),'g');
regexsistema.lastIndex = 0;    // por si acaso
var tmp, posic = [];
while (tmp = regexsistema.exec(texto)) {
    posic[posic.length] = tmp.index+tmp[1].length;
    regexsistema.lastIndex = tmp.index+cadena.length;
}
console.log(posic);            // imprime [ 2, 5, 7 ]
```